# I am tring to make a discord bot that wait for the user message and if three tags are mentioned it give tick reaction

Tags: python, discord, bots

when so many people type at once my bot skips some of the messages

Here is some of my code

````
while True:
        m=await bot.wait_for('message',check=lambda message: message.channel==ctx.message.channel and message.author!=bot.user)
        tags =m.mentions
        if len(tags) >= 3:
            await m.add_reaction("✅")
        else:
            await m.add_reaction("❌")```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `on_message` event to catch *every* message and do what you like with it.  This is better than waiting for a message and executing code as this is faster.  The downside is the channel must be hard-coded or use a global variable.  Or, you could recreate the whole command in the function (though I don't know if there are any other implications with this).

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel == bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID_HERE_AS_INT):
        tags = message.mentions
        if len(tags) >= 3:
            await message.add_reaction("✅")
        else:
            await message.add_reaction("❌")
```

Comment: how to i can use on_message in my code ..i hv gievn my code as answer please see

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your ans but how i can use on_message here

````
    await ctx.send( '__**Registrations Open**__ \n<@&711760180848885870>')
    teamlist=[]
    messlist=[]
    while True:
        m=await bot.wait_for('message',check=lambda message: message.channel==ctx.message.channel and message.author!=bot.user)
        tags =m.mentions
        if len(tags) >= 3:
            await m.add_reaction("✅")
        else:
            await m.add_reaction("❌")
            continue
        messlist.append(m)
        if len(messlist)==22:
            break
    for m in messlist:
        role=get(m.author.guild.roles , name="IDP-7pm")
        await m.author.add_roles(role)
        strr=m.content
        n=strr.find("\n")
        strr=strr[:n]
        n=strr.find(":")
        if n==-1:
            n=strr.find("-")
        if n!=-1:
            strr  =strr[n+1:]
        print(strr)
        for s in strr:
            if s.isalpha() or s.isnumeric():
                break
            else:
                strr =strr[1:]
        teamlist.append(strr)
    await ctx.send( '__**Registrations Closed**__ \n<@&711760180848885870>')
    await ch.send(f"```{Newlist}```")
    print(Newlist)```
````

Comment: You can't.  It has to be it's own function.  If you can figure out how to put all that in a separate function and call it in its own thread (so the while loop doesn't wait for it to complete) then it will run much faster.

Comment: I am working on it from 2-3 weeks still can't figure out ...can u pls give some hints how i can do ..i'll be happy if u help